# How to setup module: Referer to Entity Reference

Tags: entities, 9

i tried to use this in url:

```
site.com/node/add/material/?field_material_category=6
```

content type 'material' has entity field 'field_material_category'

number '6' is nid of node content type 'material_category'

But this url link doesnt work at all, field is empty....

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pre-fill a field value on the add form with the query string, you can use the [Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module.

Comment: @OnengLar You need to read the docs, which is why your question has a negative score.  The module page I linked to has an example with code showing how to use prepopulate with an entity reference field.